# Button not working in a different tab than the default one

Tags: javascript, html

I made some tabs on my page but buttons don't work unless they are on the home tab.
Also all js code i put below an event listener that is connected to a button in a different tab than default one does not work.

https://github.com/Vritta531/Vritta

I really don't know if this issue is related to the way I coded tabs or something else.
I'm still a beginner.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I couldn't find a "uppickaxe" purchase event in your game.js.

Comment: It's there. At the bottom. Cuz anything I put below it does not work.

Comment: See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move your `<script>` tag to the bottom right before the `<body>` end.

If you run your code and check the browser console it's saying:

"**game.js:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at game.js:116**"

**Cause:** Because you put the `<script>` tag before button with `id="uppickaxe"`. Since your script tag occurs before the element exists so it returned as **undefined/null**.

```
...
<!-- INITIALLY HERE
<script src="game.js"></script>
 -->
  
<div id="Shop" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Shop</h3>
    <button id="uppickaxe">Pickaxe || 1000 Wood</button>
</div>

<div id="Settings" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Settings</h3>
    <h3>Work in progress...</h3>
</div>

<!-- MOVE JS HERE -->
<script src="game.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```